# Unity pong game ball physics slowing issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my game for pong, the ball is supposed to bounce and never become slower. However, the ball is steadily slowing down over time. I will put an image of the ball object and the scripts.
 Here is the ball properties on the left
[image]

Here is the ball script
         using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Ball : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float ballVelocity = 3000;

```
Rigidbody rb;
bool isPlay;
int randInt;

void Awake()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    randInt = Random.Range(1,3);
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && isPlay == false)
    {
        transform.parent = null;
        isPlay = true;
        rb.isKinematic = false;
        if (randInt == 1)
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector3(ballVelocity, ballVelocity, 0));
        }
        if (randInt == 2)
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector3(-ballVelocity, -ballVelocity, 0));
        }
    }
}
```

}

and here is the bounce physics image
[image]

and since I have no idea why it won't work, here is my physics project settings
[image]

I have been stuck and am new to unity so any help would be awesome! If you need any more info, comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to you assets folder and create a [PhysicMaterial](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicMaterial.html) and set both Frictions to (Static and Dynamic) to 0 and Bounciness to 0.

Comment: whatre u talkin bout

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice the material in the second image. Other thing you could also try is adding the second parameter to the `AddForce` methods. Try using `ForeMode.Acceleration` (since I'm assuming you want to ignore the object mass) if you want to consider the mass then use `ForeMode.Force`. If none of these work, one more thing you could try is to use `transform.forward` instead of `ballVelocity`.